# twitter bootstrap table with adsense

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, adsense, autosize

I am trying to have a page with 3 autosize responsive adsense ads.
I get one left justified and no more. What else do I need to get three
across the page.I have only included the important stuff (hopefully)

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">           </script>  
<script rc="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script> 

<div class="container">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- autosize -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-44444444444444"
     data-ad-slot="42222222222"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>

</td>    
<td>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- autosize -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-44444444444444"
     data-ad-slot="42222222222"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>  
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});  
</script>  

</td>  
</tr>
.........
</tbody>

</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using table instead of responsive grid? And your table is missing rows.

Comment: will check out responsive grid thanks